# How to view a CSV file in a windows command prompt itself?

Tags: csv, cmd

The linux command for viewing csv file in terminal is:

```
cat filename.csv
```

What i use in a windows command prompt for the same thing

I can open the csv file in excel through cmd but i can't view it in the cmd.

I searched a lot and couldn't get..

Comment: The Windows command is **`type`**. Please check the answers here: https://superuser.com/questions/434870/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-command-cat

Answer (score 2):

For simply viewing a file, use the `more` command for better control, and it works on both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, in the command prompt you can simply use the `type` syntax to display the csv file content:

```
c:\>type [filename.csv]
```